# Sharing a single window/application on OS X thru VNC?

Tags: macos, software-rec, vnc

I'd like to share a single application (or window) via VNC so I can have another user use an application on my OS X box.

The closest thing I've found is [SharedAppVNC](http://shared-app-vnc.sourceforge.net/) but it doesn't seem to play well with other VNC clients (it uses its own)

Alternatively I could use a VNC server that simply lets you adjust the resolution so I can force a certain area of the screen to be shared (however this is not ideal).

Comment: Why are you trying to share only one application via VNC?

Comment: If it's an X application, just start it up in the window manager inside the VNC server display …

Comment: Nope, it's a Cocoa app, one I can only run on OS X. Why you gotta ask so many questions :)

Answer (score 1):

## Besides the application listed I don't think so.

You may however be able to send it over SSH as an X11 application, but I have little experience with that.